# Print the build number on an asp.net mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have an asp.net mvc 4 application which prints the assembly number in the header.
I have setup continuous integration and deployment to azure. 
I have setup my build number very simple to:   $(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)

I would like to print that number also in the application.
Right now I am printing the assembly number:

```
@typeof(FullStackSampleApplication.MvcApplication).Assembly.GetName().Version
```

[image]

Comment: Your questions are more like tasks hence the downvote (not by me), you showed how you print the assembly version, but there is no effort on the asked question.

Comment: lol thats funny, there is no other way to ask this question. I have searched on the internet for days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question - mvc app has no understanding of the info from the build, hence you don't have access to the build number value from the mvc app. You will have to pass this value from build either into a version.txt file or bake into AssemblyInfo.cs (for example AssemblyInformationalVersion property) or any other place (config file, db, etc.) where your application can retrieve the value later.